# how to use utf8 urls in the address bar

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, utf-8

I'm trying to implement urls like the one below:

- www.example.com/contact-us

,but with one exception, that is I want it to be utf8, like the one below:

- www.example.com/تماس-با-ما

How to do this? my webpages name are in English and I want it to be English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using .htaccess, you can redirect your visitors from /علیرضا to contact.php

In your .htaccess, write like the following,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^علیرضا$ contact.php
```

To display UTF-8 content and URLs in a page, you need to have the following in your head section.

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
```

In your `anchor` links, use utf-8 url in the href.

```
<a href="www.example.com/تماس-با-ما ">www.example.com/تماس-با-ما </a>
```

An example of `tamil` url (UTF-8) is shown below.

[image]